# html5 desktop notification pagevisibility close

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

I'm working with desktop notifications everything works fine here is the code I'm using:

```
function notifyMe(title,icon,body,tag) {        
    var notification = new Notification(title, {
        icon: icon,
        body: body,
        tag: tag
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        notification.close();
    },6000);
}
```

Now what I want is how I can close the notification without showing a notification for example if a notification is appearing , how can I close it from another function or something like that. because I want to work with pagevisibility when tab is hidden it will show notification and when tab is visible I want to hide the notification.

Comment: can share more detail ?

Comment: @trungk18 like what sir?

Comment: You mean you want to close the notification before it can be showed?

Comment: yes exactly @trungk18 and again if the notification is shown  , and when I switch from hidden pagevisibility to not hidden the notification will close , just like facebook is doing